# Different output between VS code and python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am quite new to VS code and I am trying very simple tasks in Python in without great success.

So far I installed Python 3.12.1 on my Mac and also downloaded the plugins "Code runner", "Python" and "Pylance" within VS code (I did everything on the same day). I am just following the instructions of a Udemy corse.

However, while typing the simple following commands, the output of VS code is a bit weird to me and different as I write the same in my terminal:

[The output of the basic print() function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G6WS.png)

Moreover, while changing the parameter `sep=` from default to something else (like `sep = "--"`), VS code gives me an error, **while the same command works just fine in the terminal**.

[The error I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFPEm.png)

I suspect there is something wrong in VS code but I can't figure out what.

PS: the version of Python running in VS code matches that of what it should be (3.12.1)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Apparently you're trying to use Python 2.x, where `print` is a _statement_ and `print("some", "thing")` would be valid syntax (printing a tuple) but `print("some", sep="thing")` would not.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that was my assumption too but it looks to be valid syntax for 2.7 at least. https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#print

Comment: @MatthewGreen read the **Note** in those docs...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well shoot, I missed that.

Comment: so you are running with Code Runner instead of the Python extension?

Answer (score 1):

So, like others mentioned it is the problem with the version, although u did mention u r using python 3.x, It is running fine in my vs code and IDLE. When I tried to run in an online 2.x interpreter it matched the error.

Things u can check are:

- python version command in vs code terminal
- see if you have 2.x installed too, maybe u haven't set the path to 3.x version u downloaded.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the official extension **Python** executing script.

[image]

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial